# Isomorphism of homology groups through cell boundary formula

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $\phi_\alpha \colon D^{n}_{\alpha} \to X^n$ be the attaching map of an n-cell to the nth skeleton of a CW complex and $p_\alpha \colon X^n \to X^n/(X^n-\phi_\alpha (int(D^{n}_\alpha))=S^{n-1}$ the quotient map collapsing the rest of the complex except the interior of the cell, I need help showing that $(p_\alpha \circ \phi_\alpha)_{*}$ induces isomorphisms between $H_*(D^{n}_{\alpha},\partial D^{n}_{\alpha})$ and $H_*(S^{n-1})$